# Trying to publish an AIR for iOS app using Flash CS5.5, but no ipa is being produced

Tags: ios, air, publishing, ipa

I've finally obtained an iOS developer license, I've managed to publish a hello world, basic kind of app, get an IPA file and install it on my iphone.

However, now i'm trying something more complex, including using imported libraries.  I start the publish process as usual, no error is produced but i'm not getting a message that the ipa is ready.

When i look at the target directory I have folders named like 'AOTBuildOutput5264907783565294361.tmp' with files in them.

Looks like it crashes in the middle, but I get no error message to debug!

Please help me find out where I can read these error messages or provide some other kind of insight!

Thanks in advance
Rotem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving my development folder to somewhere else in my filesystem and everything went fine.  I guess having hebrew charachters in the path didn't work so well for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I've occasionally run into problems like this. It usually occurs when I'm trying to publish the app from my dropbox folder whilst it is trying to sync.

I can only assume that the problem happens because another application is accessing that file (in my case dropbox).

So make sure nothing else is trying to sync to that folder. Hope that helps.

Comment: Colin, that didn't solve my problem, but gave me a good idea on where to check, see my solution. Thanks!